# Building Android User Interface Modification

Tags: android, user-interface, building

I am new to Android.It is new for me .I try a lot to modify my UI but i cant.i need some help to fix my UI Which shown image.my code which i did effort.i hope any one help me to fix my issue................................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
a:layout_width="match_parent"
a:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    a:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
    a:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <Button
        a:text="^"
        a:id="@+id/up"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        a:text="&lt;"
        a:id="@+id/left"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
        a:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <Button
        a:text="0"
        a:id="@+id/center"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_below="@+id/up"
        a:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        a:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <Button
        a:text="&gt;"
        a:id="@+id/right"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
        a:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <Button
        a:text="v"
        a:id="@+id/down"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_below="@+id/center"
        a:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    a:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="match_parent"
    a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    a:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
    a:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i want my UI like that see the link

[image]

Comment: Why your have written `a:` in your whole layout ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="192.168.0.500"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stream"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton1"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton2"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Up"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="left"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonCenter"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="center"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCenter"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="right"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonCenter"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Down"
            android:id="@+id/button4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just replace image with yours in ImageView.